# What is the best way to execute a .php file from android many times in background?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

What is the best way to execute a .php file from android in the background?
I need that for refreshing the user activity time in a mysql database.
So if the user clicks on a button a new entry should be done in the db with his last active datatime.

Should I use an asynctask for it like that?

```
private class UpdateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //I don't like to have a dialog. This hinds the user while he is using the app

    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        String BENUTZER_NAME = actual_tUsername;

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BENUTZER_NAME", BENUTZER_NAME));

        //Call the php file defined as string which is updating the users last online datetime
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_activetime,
                "POST", params);

        if(json == null){
            Log.v("NULL", "NULL");
        }


        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    }

}
```

Or should I better use runOnUiThread?
Or is there a better way to solve this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEVER do a network call on the UI thread (As of android 4.0 I believe, it will throw an error). Always do it in a separate thread (AsyncTask will work).

Comment: Okay. So I will use asynctaks for that! Thanks :D